# libphonenumber [Js] get country code only

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, libphonenumber

I'm using [libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/tree/master/javascript) with the [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-libphonenumber).

The problem I have is this one:

```
// Get an instance of `PhoneNumberUtil`. 
var phoneUtil = require('googlelibphonenumber').PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();

phoneUtil.parse('+44') // throws exception
phoneUtil.parse('+44234') // gives me an object to work with
```

I need to be able to parse a number which **can** be complete or not. In the worst case scenario, it will be **just the country code**. And in this case, I want to be able to get the country for it.

Is there a way to accomplish it? The API is not very documented and I'm just experimenting with the REPL while looking at the sources.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't always find out the country given a phone code because, say, USA and Canada both have `1` code.

For incomplete numbers you can try using `asYouType` and then access the `.country` property as explained here:

https://github.com/halt-hammerzeit/libphonenumber-js

Comment: after trying a while, we decided to go for a different solution. Nonetheless, I think your answer is correct: I also was falling back on `asYouType` method for performing a _check_